# Sql Server 2008 R2: AppDomain is marked for unload due to memory pressure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, memory, clr

I am running Sql Server 2008 R2 Express with a database used by a service. The database is attached via AttachDBFileName option at service startup. The service runs constantly and restarts only after automatic updates.

Sometimes, this pattern appears in Sql Server Log:

```
10/09/2013 11:18:05,spid18s,Unknown,AppDomain 6 (..MDF.dbo[runtime].5) unloaded.
10/09/2013 11:18:05,spid1s,Unknown,AppDomain 6 (...MDF.dbo[runtime].5) is marked for unload due to memory pressure.
10/09/2013 11:16:16,spid53,Unknown,AppDomain 6 (....MDF.dbo[runtime].5) created.
10/09/2013 11:16:00,spid28s,Unknown,AppDomain 5 (....MDF.dbo[runtime].4) unloaded.
10/09/2013 11:16:00,spid1s,Unknown,AppDomain 5 (....MDF.dbo[runtime].4) is marked for unload due to memory pressure.
10/09/2013 11:15:41,spid53,Unknown,AppDomain 5 (...MDF.dbo[runtime].4) created.
10/09/2013 11:14:20,spid24s,Unknown,AppDomain 4 (...MDF.dbo[runtime].3) unloaded.
10/09/2013 11:14:20,spid1s,Unknown,AppDomain 4 (...MDF.dbo[runtime].3) is marked for unload due to memory pressure.
```

This causes performance problems, because every time the AppDomain is restarted, buffers are dropped and the database is unresponsive for a few seconds.

According to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/917271?wa=wsignin1.0, it might be due to memory leaks or other errors in CLR modules (even though I suppose that should be fixed in Sql Server 2008 R2). There is one CLR module installed, with the following code:

```
[Serializable]
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlUserDefinedAggregate(Format.UserDefined, 
    MaxByteSize=8000)]
public class Concatenate : IBinarySerialize
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The variable that holds the intermediate result of the concatenation
    /// </summary>
    private StringBuilder intermediateResult;

    public void Init()
    {
        // Put your code here
        intermediateResult = new StringBuilder();
    }

    public void Accumulate(SqlString Value)
    {
        if (Value.IsNull)
            return;

        intermediateResult.Append(Value.Value).Append(", ");
    }

    public void Merge(Concatenate Group)
    {
        intermediateResult.Append(Group.intermediateResult);
    }

    public SqlString Terminate()
    {
        string output = string.Empty;
        //delete the trailing comma, if any
        if (intermediateResult != null && intermediateResult.Length > 0)
            output = intermediateResult.ToString(0, intermediateResult.Length - 2);

        return new SqlString(output);
    }

    #region IBinarySerialize Members

    public void Read(System.IO.BinaryReader r)
    {
        if (r == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("r");
        intermediateResult = new StringBuilder(r.ReadString());
    }

    public void Write(System.IO.BinaryWriter w)
    {
        if (w == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("w");
        w.Write(intermediateResult.ToString());
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Also, MS Exchange is running on the server, using up 90% of free memory for MDB store. However I saw this errors in the past on other servers with heaps of free memory, so I suppose the memory pressure is not the real cause of the problem.

Any ideas what could cause this problem?

Comment: You wrote a statement of facts here. What's the question?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here and read if you have the same problem: https://teusje.wordpress.com/2015/05/07/slow-performance-on-asp-net-mvc-application-using-entityframework-sql-server/